# Entity is of bundle values in Rules

Tags: rules, 9

I've created a very basic "reaction rule" on "After updating a order".

I can't figure out what I need to fill in for: "Entity is of bundle" for the fields if I want to get Order fields:

1. Type
2. Bundle

I have tried all variants like "Type= Order" and "Bundle= default" etc, but it just doesn't work.

Anyone has it working with Entity is of bundle for Commerce Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found it.

1. Type= commerce_order
2. Bundle= default

I'll leave it here in case anyone searches for it. It is not documented anywhere.